# Find duplicates in desired column and print the selected patterns in awk?

Tags: linux, sed, awk

Input file:  Input.txt

```
A B C
1 rs1 5
1 kp1 5
1 rs2 6
1 ga2 6
1 rs8 9
2 kp3 7
2 rs3 7
2 rs4 5
2 rs5 8
3 kp6 4
3 kp7 6
```

For each category in column **A** (example: 1, 2  and 3) separately look for duplicates in column **C**. If there are duplicate numbers the print a list of non **rs** IDs in each category in separate files.

Output files:

file_category_1.txt

```
A B C
1 kp1 5
1 ga2 6
```

file_category_2.txt

```
A B C
2 kp3 7
```

file_category_3.txt

```
A B C
```

Here file_category_3.txt will not have any output because no duplicates in it.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you most of the way there

```
awk 'NR==1 {print; next} seen[$1,$3]++ {print}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested but should be close:

```
awk '
NR==1 {
   hdr = $0
   next
}
{
   cnt[$1,$3]++
   cats[$1]
   ids[$2]
   map[$1,$3,$2] = $0
}
END {
   for (cat in cats) {
      print hdr > "file_category_" cat ".txt"
   }
   for (key in cnt) {
      if (cnt[key] > 1) {
         split(key,keyA,SUBSEP)
         for (id in ids) {
            if ((key,id) in map) {
               print map[key,id] > "file_category_" keyA[1] ".txt"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}' file
```

Comment: +1 Your solution looks like it would work, but I don't see a check for non-'rs' id's. This can easily be fixed. However, personally, I would use a better data structure (see my answer) even if it makes it GNU only. Portability vs readability.

Answer (score 0):

not too difficult: Here is the oneliner you can do, in pseudo-code:

for category in 1 2 3 ; grep on field $1 for that category | keep only $3 $2 (in that order)| sort | uniq -c | grep -v "lines with only 1 count" | grep -v "any occurence of 'rs' in $2 field" > file_category_$category.txt

But, as Clement pointed out, you should do part of the work ^^ That's why it's only pseudo-code (but can be straightforwardly put into actual code in maybe 3mn)

Answer (score 0):

You've actually got two problems here, both of which can be accomplished using `awk`.

First, you need to first split the file up into smaller files:

```
awk 'NR==1 { r=$0; next } { print ($1==i ? "" : r ORS) $0 > "file_category_" $1 ".txt"; i=$1 }' input.txt
```

Second, you need filter the smaller files based on your selection criteria:

```
for i in file_category_*.txt; do awk 'FNR==NR { a[$3]++; next } FNR==1 || a[$3]>1 && $2 !~ /^rs/' "$i"{,} > tmp && mv tmp "$i"; done
```

Here's the result of `grep . file_category_*.txt`:

```
file_category_1.txt:A B C
file_category_1.txt:1 kp1 5
file_category_1.txt:1 ga2 6
file_category_2.txt:A B C
file_category_2.txt:2 kp3 7
file_category_3.txt:A B C
```

---

---

Alternatively, if you have `GNU awk` and require a single pass solution, you could do the same thing using a multidimensional array. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
NR==1 {
    r=$0
    next
}

{
    a[$1][$3][$0]
    next
}

END {
    for (i in a) {
        for (j in a[i]) {
            for (k in a[i][j]) {

                split(k,b)
                print (n==1 ? "" : r ORS) \
                    (length(a[i][j])>1 ?  \
                    (b[2] !~ /^rs/ ? k : "") : "") \
                    > "file_category_" i ".txt"
                n=1
            }
        }
        n=0
    }
}
```

Here's the result of `grep . file_category_*.txt`:

```
file_category_1.txt:A B C
file_category_1.txt:1 kp1 5
file_category_1.txt:1 ga2 6
file_category_2.txt:A B C
file_category_2.txt:2 kp3 7
file_category_3.txt:A B C
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==1 { r=$0; next } { a[$1][$3][$0]; next } END { for (i in a) { for (j in a[i]) for (k in a[i][j]) { split(k,b); print (n==1 ? "" : r ORS) (length(a[i][j])>1 ? (b[2] !~ /^rs/ ? k : "") : "") > "file_category_" i ".txt"; n=1 } n=0 } }' input.txt
```

Comment: its showing errors as follows

awk: script.awk:7:     a[$1][$3][$0]
awk: script.awk:7:          ^ syntax error
awk: script.awk:13:         for (j in a[i]) {
awk: script.awk:13:                    ^ syntax error
awk: script.awk:14:             for (k in a[i][j]) {
awk: script.awk:14:                        ^ syntax error
awk: script.awk:18:                     (length(a[i][j])>1 ?  \
awk: script.awk:18:                                 ^ syntax error

Comment: @IsmeetKaur: It looks like you're not using GNU awk (`gawk`). Only `gawk` has the ability to use a true multidimensional array (as opposed to pseudo-multidimensional arrays). If you do decide to install it, I can guarantee it'll save you a lot of time and effort in the future too. Can I ask what version you are using?